# How to pass the address of an array to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I just wanted to ask on how to pass the *address* of an array to a function.

```
void me( int *a ) {
    printf("%d\n", *a); // that gives me 11
}

int main () {
    int x[3]  = { 11, 12, 13 };

    me(&x[0]);

return 0;
}
```

But what if I want to pass the whole array not by repeating the me(&x[//the position I want to pass]);

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried it? Pass `&x`, or even passing `x` causes implicit conversion ('decay') to a pointer. As such, it doesn't achieve anything really different from passing a pointer to the first element. If the function can be passed different arrays, or each array's size isn't fixed, you should pass the size too, so that your function knows how far it can index from the first element.

Comment: &x[0] is equivalent to x. It's the same, the address of the first element in your array. But here you're just using a single element so you don't need dealing with arrays.

Comment: Can you please give me an example base on my question. im noob only

Comment: How do you take the address of a thing? You put `&` in front of the thing. What is the thing? `x`. Try `&x`. Have you got a C book or tried searching for tutorials? They will all explain basic language features like this very early on.

Comment: @underscore_d `x` (or `&x[0]`) is *not* the same as `&x`. The first is a pointer to `int`, the other is a pointer to `int[3]`, a very big difference. The addresses are the same, but the type is not.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, the OP was asking how to "pass the whole array". And that's how. They might not really _want_ to ask that, but it answers it.

Comment: To explicitly state this: Its is **not possible** to "*pass an array*" in C. All one can do is pass the address of its 1st element by just doing `me(x)`  (where the array `x` decays the address of its 1st element)  or pass the array's address by doing `me(&x)`. The latter is *only* necessary if the value of `x` should be changed inside the function, which is not possible for the OP's code as `x` is an array variable.

Answer (score 6):

All other answers are good, only a thing to add, form my point of you.

You shoul add a parameter to your function to be able to use it with different arrays with different lengths, so pass the length of array to `me` function

```
#include <stdio.h>

void me( int *a, size_t length ) {
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
       printf("Element %zu is %d\n", i, a[i]);
}

int main () {

    int x[3]  = { 11, 12, 13 };

    me(x, sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I used [sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) which returns the bytes length of the array. So dividing it with the size in bytes of a single element of the array. The result is the number of elements of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Address of the array is same as the address of the first element. To print the rest of the elements just increment the pointer like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void me( int *a ) {
    printf("%d\n", *a); // that gives me 11
    printf("%d\n", *(a+1)); // will give you 12
    printf("%d\n", *(a+2)); // will give you 13
}

int main () {

    int x[3]  = { 11, 12, 13 };

    me(&x[0]);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

But you *are* passing the "whole array" to the function. By passing a pointer to the first element you are in fact passing a pointer to the rest of the elements too.

To print out the second element of the array, modify the function such as this:

```
void me( int *a ) {
    printf("%d\n", a[1]); // prints the second element in a
}
```

This works because for any array *or pointer* `a` and index `i` the expression `a[i]` is the same as `*(a + i)`.

Also note that simply passing `x` is the same as passing `&x[0]`, as arrays naturally decays to a pointer to its first element. So the call could just be

```
me(x);  // Same as me(&x[0])
```

Comment: but it gives me a Warning that passing arg 1 of 'me' from incompatible pointer type ..

Comment: @DisplayName are you sure? What is your compiler?

Comment: @DisplayName The code, as you shown it, should not cause such a warning.

Answer (score 1):

when you pass array name to a function , It will automatically pass the address of the first element of the array.so we can loop the address and access other elements also.You can try this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void me( int *a) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%d\n",*(a+i));
    }
}

int main () {

    int x[3]  = { 11, 12, 13 };

    me(x);

return 0;
}
```

output

```
11
12
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can pass entire array to function. So,

```
 me(x); //Pass only name of array
```

Array hold the starting address of elements means `x[0]` address.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void me( int *a) {
    int i=0;
    while (i<3)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*(a+i));
        i++;
    }
}

int main () {

    int x[3]  = { 11, 12, 13 };

    me(x);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Choose between these two:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void me(int *a, int length) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i<length){
      printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
      i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x[3]  = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    me(x, sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

**Or**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void me(int *a, int length) {
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
      printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, *(a+i));
}

int main() {
    int x[3]  = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    me(x, sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]));

    return 0;
}
```